# Flutter run command error : FlutterView.send called on a detached view

Tags: dart, flutter

Can anyone tell me why my app is not installing at all and ending with the error message

Observatory connection never became ready.

the app was working perfectly fine until yesterday .

I have changed the channel to master yesterday in the command prompt and from then on the app never runs.

I even switched back to channel alpha but still no use.

I have attached a screenshot of the command prompt where the installation was stuck forever.

I am not so sure if I need to reinstall the flutter. I am worried if I uninstall the flutter now it may not configure properly and I might break it forever.

Please can someone tell me what exactly might have gone wrong.

Many Thanks,
Mahi

[image: Screenshot of command prompt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is from Google Groups @Flutter-Dev

Thank you very much for your reply @Michael Thomsen.

I've tried what you have suggested and the details are as follows:

1. When I used `flutter run -v` command the command prompt output is as follows:
   It was stuck for a while at `waiting for port connection` if I am not wrong.

So I've used `AndroidStudio`, `File>Open` and selected `android/`  folder to run the app then the `gradle` was showing an error:

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (25.2.0) and test app (25.4.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

I modified the `build.gradle`(Module:app) to show the correct version of 25.2.0 which was previously showing 25.4.0.

```
 dependencies {
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
  }
```

I just saved the changes inside android studio and the gradle sync completed without any errors.

Now I can run the app from inside Android Studio and also from IntelliJ IDE.

Thanks very much Michael this solved my problem.

Comment: My problem was different, but opening android project separately allowed me to find and fix the issue.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of reinstall try with following: (Mac)

- Set Path Variable: via following terminal command

  `export PATH=~/flutter/bin:$PATH;`

that is bin folder path of flutter.

```
   export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_FOLDER]/bin:$PATH
```

https://flutter.io/setup-macos/#update-your-path

- If above not worked. Check with the Dart version

  `dart --version`

Install the latest dart version:

```
    brew install dart --devel
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 4):

For Mac
open terminal

1. $ echo $PATH
   it will show like this 
       /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
   it means you need to add flutter in to path
2. Open Finder presss command + shift + G

   Put /etc/paths in dialog and press GO
   [image]

   Copy the file "paths" and paste it on desktop
3. Then open the pasted "paths" file from desktop 
    and add following line into end of the file "/flutter/bin"
    [image]
4. Then copy that file and again paste it on /etc/paths
   same like step no 2
5. it will ask you to replace or not

   [image]

   press replace

Now if you hit $ echo $PATH on terminal it will show 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/swagat/development/flutter/bin

Now your **$flutter doctor** will work perfectly

Comment: One thing to note: At step 3, you have to put the correct actual path in your machine, not `/flutter/bin` because it is different based on where you store flutter folder

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling flutter would be my starting point. If this problem persists, please post the output of `$>flutter doctor` and a description of what exactly leads to this error.

Comment: Thank you rainer, I have tried reinstall of flutter by cloning from git but to no avail it is not throwing any error message but getting stuck like in the previous screen shot i posted with the question. I am sorry i couldn't post the flutter doctor output as the characters go over the limit  to add in a comments

Comment: i know its a bit hard to answer the question without proper details but thanks for your help @Rainer Wittman. Unfortunately i am stuck and probably have to waste a day or two to figure out what went wrong? I've tried to clone the code and it seems to be working fine on other systems but is broken on my laptop.