# Flutter: How to open main.dart

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter

With the help of [installation guide](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/#update-your-path) and this solution: [How to create a new project in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047411/flutter-how-to-create-a-new-project/49048596#49048596), I created a sample (default/demo) project in flutter for iOS and Android compatible platforms. And a default project (code) is working fine.

[image]

Now, I want to update the code of the project and according to this document guide: [Get Started: Test Drive](https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/#create-app), a file named `main.dart` is source file of project and code inside it, is the main source code.

[image]

**My problem is - How to open main.dart?**

Which editor (Xcode/Android Studio or any other tool) can help to open this file? I tried double click on the file, but it shows me a message: "legacy image should be converted".

[image]

Comment: Why not open the full project ? => `test_project`.

Comment: Open the full project in android studio. Also, you can create flutter projects from android studio very easily (if you have the flutter and dart plugins installed)

Comment: @Darky - Thank you once again for your help. How can I open full project. As you can see in source directory structure, there are two separate folder for iOS and android and according to document main.dart handle updates for both.

Comment: In flutter you should most of the time never touch /android and /ios. What you care about is the /lib. Open the `test_project` folder, and do your stuff directly on /lib/main.dart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to your question by Flutter: [Get Started: Configure Editor](https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/)

You can either use Android Studio or Visual Studio Code as a Flutter (main.dart) project editor.

Steps are also mentioned in this document, how you can open Flutter project with these editors:

## Visual Studio Code (VS Code) setup

VS Code: A light-weight editor with Flutter run and debug support.

Install VS Code: VS Code, version 1.20.1 or later.

**Install the Dart Code plugin**

1. Start VS Code
2. Invoke View>Command Palette…
3. Type ‘install’, and select the ‘Extensions: Install Extension’ action
4. Enter dart code in the search field, select ‘Dart Code’ in the list, and click Install
5. Select ‘OK’ to reload VS Code

**Validate your setup with the Flutter Doctor**

1. Invoke View>Command Palette…
2. Type ‘doctor’, and select the ‘Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor’ action
3. Review the output in the ‘OUTPUT’ pane for any issues

## Android Studio setup

Android Studio: A complete, integrated IDE experience for Flutter.

Install Android Studio: Android Studio, version 3.0 or later.

**Install the Flutter and Dart plugins**

- The Flutter plugin powers Flutter developer workflows (running, debugging, hot reload, etc.).
- The Dart plugin offers code analysis (code validation as you type, code completions, etc.).

**To install these:**

1. Start Android Studio.
2. Open plugin preferences (Preferences>Plugins on macOS,  File>Settings>Plugins on Windows & Linux).
3. Select Browse repositories…, select the Flutter plug-in and click install.
4. Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
5. Click Restart when prompted.

Answer (score 1):

Handle your flutter project with Android Studio 3.0 +.

Install plug-ins for `Dart` and `Flutter` in Android studio and then open your project (root directory) of your project in Android Studio.

1. Start Android Studio.
2. Open plugin preferences (Preferences>Plugins on macOS, File>Settings>Plugins on Windows & Linux).
3. Select Browse repositories…, select the Flutter plug-in and click install.
4. Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
5. Click Restart when prompted.

Here is sample project in Android Studio, with same name as you used in your project:

[image]

Look at this reference document: [Get Started: Configure Editor](https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/)