# How to create new Flutter application with the same package name published in playstore?

Tags: android, flutter, migration

I am trying to manually migrate my android native app into Flutter. When I setup new flutter app in android studio, the package name keep changing. I assumes this is because package name conflict since my native app already published in play store.

Current package name published in play store
`com.example.mobile.app1`

During setup new flutter app:

app name: `app1`

package name: `com.example.mobile`

(I have plan to make build variants so I only take first 3 part of current package name)

After setup, I checked manifest and build gradle file the package name changed to:

`com.example.app1`

Comment: Why don't you just change it back to com.example.mobile?

Comment: ignore the manifest,the only place you need to change it is on build.gradle (app folder)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54606772/10409567